# How to detect when an AutoCompleteTextView popup is opened?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

How can I do something when a popup just opens? There is a method `isPopupShowing()`, but nothing like `onPopupShow()` callback unfortunately.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? do you want to do something before popup opens?

Comment: @Clairvoyant I want send a message to my statistic server about this popup is opens :) Before or after is not matter, I just want to know that popup is guaranteed opens and count this on server.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late. Better late than never.

If popup is only shown when user clicks on `AutoCompleteTextView`, we can set `OnClickListener` to it and check if popup is shown.

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (autoCompleteTextView.isPopupShowing()){
            //Do what you want
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, dont know if there is an easier way, and this is a bit of a workaround, but you could try adding a `TextWatcher` via `addTextChangedListener` and do a  `isPopupShowing()` to check if popup is up. Again its a bit of workaround and wont work if you prorammatically show the popup.

Comment: This solution is very close to my purpose, one problem is I can rely on  `isPopupShowing()` only after second text changing and can't detect popup immediately on first appear.

Comment: Hm, as an alternative you could try to override the `onFilterComplete(int count)` method of the `AutocompleteTextView` and check there if count > 0 which would mean that there is at least one value to show on popup, so the popup should be visible at the time. This would need some testing to find out if it really works that way :)

Comment: @EvripidisDrakos your proposal is the best way to do this.If you have some filter results, and the popup is not currently showing (isPopupShowing()), then you know that you're about to show it. Using the text changed events will not work; even afterTextChanged() occurs before the popup is shown.

Answer (score 0):

My answer could be a little bit different but it works when you have valid results.

1.- Extend your own class of `AutoCompleteTextView`:

```
public class ContractsAutoCompleteTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView {
    public ContractsAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ContractsAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ContractsAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

}
```

2.- We know that `onFilterComplete(int count)` will get notified when items are filtered (and just later shown). Introduce that in your class:

```
    @Override
    public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
        super.onFilterComplete(count);
    }
```

3.- Create an `interface` to notify the UI how many items are filtered every time you change text:

```
    interface OnContractsAvailability {
        void contractsRetrieved(int count);
    }

    private OnContractsAvailability onContractsAvailability;
    public void setOnContractsAvailability(OnContractsAvailability onContractsAvailability) {
        this.onContractsAvailability = onContractsAvailability;
    }
```

4.- Now notify your `interface`:

```
    @Override
    public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
        super.onFilterComplete(count);
        if (onContractsAvailability != null) {
            onContractsAvailability.contractsRetrieved(count);
        }
    }
```

**This is the whole class**

```
/**
 * Created by rafaelruizmunoz on 07/07/2017.
 */

public class ContractsAutoCompleteTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView {
    public ContractsAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ContractsAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ContractsAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
        super.onFilterComplete(count);
        if (onContractsAvailability != null) {
            onContractsAvailability.contractsRetrieved(count);
        }
    }

    interface OnContractsAvailability {
        void contractsRetrieved(int count);
    }

    private OnContractsAvailability onContractsAvailability;
    public void setOnContractsAvailability(OnContractsAvailability onContractsAvailability) {
        this.onContractsAvailability = onContractsAvailability;
    }
}
```

**This is the UI implementation**

```
    contractsET.setOnContractsAvailability(count -> System.out.println(String.valueOf(count)));
```

**And these are the results**

> 07-07 11:51:36.975 32174-32174/? I/System.out: 3138
>
> 07-07 11:51:37.520 32174-32174/? I/System.out: 1147
>
> 07-07 11:51:37.656 32174-32174/? I/System.out: 167
>
> 07-07 11:51:38.538 32174-32174/? I/System.out: 87
>
> 07-07 11:51:39.240 32174-32174/? I/System.out: 17
>
> 07-07 11:51:40.039 32174-32174/? I/System.out: 3
>
> 07-07 11:51:41.343 32174-32174/? I/System.out: 0

Answer (score 0):

```
if (autoCompleteText.enoughToFilter()) {
  // do something
}
```