# Android AutoCompleteTextView - listener when suggestion popup is being shown or hidden

Tags: android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

Is there a way to detect when an AutoCompleteTextView shows or hides its suggestions popup? (suggestions shown/hidden listener)

Comment: This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429185/android-detecting-when-a-autocompletetextview-popup-is-opened)